# Regional Iso Code vs Iso Code

Tags: multilingual

I'm working on something which requires giving the content editor a language selector. After selecting languages, a group of items should have any language except the selected languages removed. The language selector uses the actual language items. These have an `iso` field and `regional iso code` field.

When a language item has both an `iso` and `regional iso code`, passing either field value to `LanguageManager.GetLanguage` will result in a language. It looks like items will only have versions for either the iso code language or regional iso code language but not both though.

How do I know when to use the regional iso code vs the regular iso code given a certain language item that has values for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `Regional` or `ISO` code, you can directly ***use the item name*** instead. Sitecore will always create the languages using the Regional Code. Examples:

- en-US
- en
- da
- af-ZA

So, if you use the item name, you don't need to check if the field `Regional` or `ISO` has a value.

Comment: Great that makes things easier for me. Thanks!